# How to Access local JSON file response in NSDictionary for showing in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

Basically I got response from server side and then i saved it in local file.Actually I fetched the response from server side and then saved into documents directory ,and now trying to fetch but it comes in NSString only ,i unable to get in NSDictionary....Here is following code

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *URLString = @"http://localhost/rest/login";

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager =[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": userNameTxtField.text, @"password": pwdTextField.text};
    NSLog(@"Parameters:\n%@",params);

    [manager POST:URLString parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject)
    {

        NSLog(@"Successfully Login ....: %@", responseObject);

        NSString *documents = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sample.json", documents];

        NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:path append:YES];
        [stream open];

        NSError  *writeError = nil;

        NSInteger bytesWritten = [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:responseObject toStream:stream options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

        if ((bytesWritten = 0))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error writing JSON Data");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Sucessfuly saved data...");
        }
          [stream close];

        NSLog(@"path is :%@",path);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error)

    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (IBAction)fetch:(id)sender
{
    NSError *deserializingError;
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&deserializingError];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"vaues are:%@",dict);
}
```

Comment: Get the data from response and save it array and load into table.

Comment: Instead of store it in local file. You can save it Core Data, Sqlite and NSUserDefault. So, you can get from any where of your application.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have to maintain too many files so i should maintain file format ,actually i got the content in NSData but which is in bytes format,so i want to fetch them as a key and value format.

Answer (score 0):

Your response object should be a type of NSDictionary. Therefore you can use its writeToFileAtPath method to save it to your documents directory.

When recreating the dictionary, you can use the NSDictionary's alloc and initWithContentsOfFile method to directly create a NSDictionary instance.

There are tons of posts on how to do that if you do a little Google search!

Comment: >Your response object should be a type of NSDictionary.  Really?

Comment: Hi El Tomato. This person that specified the following LOC. That means the library will parse the json and convert it to foundation objects if I'm right.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

Comment: hi EI tomato yes.. my resposeObject is an nsdictionary format ,containing key and values

Comment: Did you try my suggestion Govind?

Comment: Hi Ruchira.. whatever i did in following code is that correct ?NSInteger bytesWritten = [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:responseObject toStream:stream options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

        if ((bytesWritten = 0))
        {
            NSLog(@"Error writing JSON Data");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Sucessfuly saved data...");
        }
          [stream close];

Comment: Hi Govind. I'm travelling now and don't have access to a computer to correctly specify. However, I can't find anything wrong with your code too. I'm assuming you have correctly configured your stream. Do you get an error from writing the stream? How many bytes do you get written?

Comment: Hi Ruchira.  I written the json content perfectly in file named as simple.json but while reading it in the form of dictionary ,i'm facing issues .also got the total 22 key value pair in my file but unable to bring out in nsdictionary ..Although it comes in NSString

Comment: Hi Govind. I notice something which might be an issue with your code. You're writing using a stream and not reading via a stream. Can you try and read via a stream too. Otherwise, use my approach. It should work. Use the following to read a stream. + (instancetype)inputStreamWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! It's working fine.

```
            NSMutableDictionary *testStore = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [testStore setObject:@"vignesh" forKey:@"username"];
            [testStore setObject:@"password" forKey:@"password"];

            NSError *error;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:testStore // Here you can pass array or dictionary
                                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                                 error:&error];
            NSString *jsonString;
            if (jsonData) {
                jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                //This is your JSON String
                //NSUTF8StringEncoding encodes special characters using an escaping scheme
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
                jsonString = @"";
            }


            [self writeStringToFile:jsonString];

            NSLog(@"Your JSON String is %@", [self readStringFromFile]);

        - (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {

            // Build the path, and create if needed.
            NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* fileName = @"bookmark.json";
            NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
            }

            // Write to file
            [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
        }

        - (NSString*)readStringFromFile {

            // Build the path...
            NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* fileName = @"bookmark.json";
            NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

            // read from file
            return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
```

Comment: this is code:     -(void)FetchData
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:FilePath];
    NSLog(@"values are %@",dictionary);
     NameArray=[dictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSMutableArray *LastNameArray=[dictionary valueForKey:@"last_name"];
    NSLog(@"First Name of student is:%@",NameArray);
    NSLog(@"Last Name of student is:%@",LastNameArray);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
static const char *dbPath = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *ermsg = nil;
static sqlite3 *studs =nil;
static DatabaseOperation *_sharedInstances = nil;

@implementation DatabaseOperation
@synthesize databasePath;

+(DatabaseOperation*)sharedInstances{
    if(!_sharedInstances){
        _sharedInstances =[[super allocWithZone:nil]init];
    }
    return _sharedInstances;
}
+(id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone{
    return  [self sharedInstances];
}
-(id)init{
    NSLog(@"Only first time Instances using Singleton:");
    self =[super init];
    if(self){
        [self CreateDbpath];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)CreateDbpath{

    NSArray *dbpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docdir=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[dbpaths objectAtIndex:0]];

    self.databasePath =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Mindset.sqlite"]];

    NSFileManager *flg  = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL isSuccess = false;

    if([flg fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO){

        char  *ermsgss = nil;

        char const *dbpathss =[self.databasePath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbpathss, &studs)==SQLITE_OK){

            char *sqlQuery ="create table if not exists emp(name text,city text,img blob)";

            if(sqlite3_exec(studs, sqlQuery, nil, nil, &ermsgss)!=SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table:");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Successfully to create table:");
            }

        }
        sqlite3_close(studs);
    }
    return isSuccess;
}

-(void)insertDatabaseValue:(DataManagers *)getInserted{

    dbPath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &studs)==SQLITE_OK){

        NSString *sqlQuery=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into emp values(?,?,?)"];

        const char *_sqlQuery=[sqlQuery UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(studs, _sqlQuery, -1, &ermsg, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

            sqlite3_bind_text(ermsg, 1, [getInserted.userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(ermsg, 2, [getInserted.cityName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            NSData *jpegData =[[NSData alloc]init];

            NSData *imgeData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(getInserted.profileImg, 0.85f);

            UIImage *imgesData =[UIImage imageWithData:imgeData];

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 150);

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

            [imgesData drawInRect:rect];

            UIImage *img =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            ;
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f);

            sqlite3_bind_blob(ermsg, 3, [jpegData bytes], [jpegData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if(sqlite3_step(ermsg)==SQLITE_DONE){

                NSLog(@"Successfully inserted into db:");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error %s",sqlite3_errmsg(studs));
            }
        }

        sqlite3_close(studs);
        sqlite3_finalize(ermsg);
    }
}

-(NSMutableArray*)getAllData {

    NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    dbPath = [self.databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &studs)==SQLITE_OK){

        NSString *sqlQuery =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select * from emp"];

        const char *_sqlQuery =[sqlQuery UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(studs, _sqlQuery, -1, &ermsg, nil)==SQLITE_OK){

            while (sqlite3_step(ermsg)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                DataManagers *mgr =[[DataManagers alloc]init];

                NSString *_Firstname = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(ermsg, 0) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(ermsg, 0)]:nil;

                mgr.userName = _Firstname;

                NSString *lastName =(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(ermsg, 1)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(ermsg, 1)]:nil;

                mgr.cityName = lastName;

                int imgBytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(ermsg, 2);

                UIImage *img =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(ermsg, 2) length:imgBytes]];

                mgr.profileImg = img;

                [array addObject:mgr];
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```